# Missing ssl library when connecting to pop3 over ssl from an activex developed in delphi-7 whith indy client 9?

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-7, indy

I'm developing an activexform with delphi 7 using the indy client (v.9) to connect to pop3 over ssl. Unfortunately when I load the activex in the web browser it tells me that it can't find the SSL library (ssleay32, libeay32).
Does anybody know how can I work around this?

(or Does anybody know any other method to connect to pop3 over ssl from an application that has to run in an Internet Explorer window?)

Michele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webbrowser's machine needs to have the OpenSSL DLLs installed somewhere on the System search path, such as in the Windows installation folder.  However, Indy v9 uses customized versions of the OpenSSL DLLs.  To be able to use the official DLLs from OpenSSL's website, you will have to upgrade to Indy 10.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to normal programs where Windows looks for dlls in the executable's directory first, it does not do so for activeX controls. So in order for it to load a dll from that directory, it must either specify the absolute path to it or it must add the executable's directory to the search path. Maybe that's why your activeX control cannot find the ssl dll?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sincerely I don't know, I've eventually dropped the idea of developing the ActiveX, I've solved my problem with a java applet, it was simpler and I found it a much more easier and cleaner approach.